# DAX: Using Column B to Retrieve Column A and THEN calculate measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have a visual table with 3 variables, Store_ID, Store_Score and Mirror_Store_ID. What I want to achieve is to calculate my score (which is a measure) over the mirror store for each row like this:

| STORE_ID | score | MIRROR_STORE_ID | mirror_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.72 | 6 | 0.92 |
| 2 | 0.98 | 5 | 0.76 |
| 3 | 0.62 | 4 | 0.90 |
| 4 | 0.90 | 3 | 0.62 |
| 5 | 0.76 | 2 | 0.98 |
| 6 | 0.92 | 1 | 0.72 |

Like a VLOOKUP would do normally but in this case this is a measure.

I have tried this but will only retrieve matching rows:

```
Score_Mirror_Store = CALCULATE([score], FILTER(StoreTable, StoreTable[STORE_ID] = StoreTable[MIRROR_SCORE_ID]))
```

Edit: Here is a picture for more context:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following measure:

```
=
VAR ThisMirrorStoreID =
    MIN( Table1[MIRROR_STORE_ID] )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        Table1[score],
        Table1[STORE_ID], ThisMirrorStoreID
    )
```

Comment: Hey Jos, thanks so much for the reply. But that would work if "score" is a measure?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if you want the total to be blank or something else, below calculation is  sum up:

```
Measure = 
SUMX('StoreTable',
     LOOKUPVALUE(StoreTable[score],
     StoreTable[MIRROR_STORE_ID],StoreTable[STORE_ID])
     )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sia, thanks for the help. The thing is that "score" is a measure I made so I can't call it from a table column.

Comment: Where did it come from? another table? then can you share the calculation of "SCORE" measure as well as the database of another table

Comment: Hi Sia. I have added to the post an image to show this. Score is a measure containing other measures.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, are Store_ID and Mirror_Store_ID from one same table? Or you can share your pbix file so I can see more details.